# Django - how to store ImageField files in different folders?

Tags: django, django-models, django-media

I've configured both `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` and this works perfectly fine.
My MEDIA files stored in a directory named `/media/`, now I want to store **newly uploaded** files to a **new directory** (for ex. **/media2/**) without breaking previous files.

For example I had a Book model like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    # name
    # author
    cover = models.ImageField()
```

Now imagine I have 500 objects of Book model, so each cover has a path and url like this:

url: `http://example.com/media/books/thumb.jpg`

path: `/home/myproj/media/books/thumb.jpg`

Now, I want to store covers for my newly created books in another directory, for ex. :

url: `http://example.com/media2/books/thumb.jpg`

path: `/home/myproj/media2/books/thumb.jpg`

without breaking previous 500 books!

How can I achieve this ?! (`Django 3.1.2`)

Answer (score 1):

it's important to upload all files to one directory. From there, you can define the `upload_to` attribute for files: "This attribute provides a way of setting the upload directory and file name, and can be set in two ways. In both cases, the value is passed to the Storage.save() method."

Here are a couple of examples from [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/uploads
  upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
  # or...
  # file will be saved to MEDIA_ROOT/uploads/2015/01/30
  upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

Or create a function to pass into the model:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but the upload_to attribute just creates a new directory in the same MEDIA_ROOT, the question I asked was about how can I have multiple MEDIA_ROOTs !

Comment: @OmidAdib my advice is to upload everything to one media root and then define subdirectories. Why would you upload to multiple media roots?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu server for production with 100GB mounted in /dev/sda1. Now it's full and I bought another volume which is mounted as /dev/sda2. That's why I want to have multiple media_roots because I can't merge these two volumes to be one!